# .NET XML serialization in 2009

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replacement for XML Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186743/replacement-for-xml-serialization)

Is something new besides [old XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) on the world of xml serialization in .Net universe?

**Update:** This is probably duplicate of [better asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186743/replacement-for-xml-serialization).

Comment: I hate ask this, but what is wrong with XmlSerializer?

Comment: @sztomi: inability to work with IEnumerable<T> really annoys me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx)

It's used by WCF by default for example. See [here](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/) for a comparison.

Personally, I hate that `XmlSerializer` can't do internal types. DataContractSerializer doesn't have that problem. Also, the `DataContractSerializer` is easier with generics for example. If you want to produce a human editable XML format, it might be less than ideal.

As [Maxim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116317/) pointed out, the `DataContractSerializer` behaves a little different from what you might expect: it doesn't call any constructor to deserialize your object. If you need to do some initialization for whatever reason, you can use the [`[OnDeserializing]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute.aspx) attribute. I use a pattern like this:

```
[DataContract]
public MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    [OnDeserializing]
    private OnDeserializing(StreamingContext context)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Similarly, there is an [`[OnDeserialized]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx) attribute, and versions for serialization as well.

Comment: Beware that constructor is not called with DataContractSerializer

Comment: Good point. It confused the hell out of me at the time before I figured that out :)